# Apache mod_rewrite not treating a rewritten url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/settings.php$ /settings.php?session=$1
RewriteRule ^/register/(.*)/(.*) /register/$2?session=$1
```

I'm putting the session in the url but it's not working.  It tries to treat the session as a file:

> [Mon Apr 16 17:37:05 2012] [error] File does not exist:
>   /home/delta/public_html/register/D7yuzHOn3gx

What is wrong with this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is looking for `/register/(.*)/(.*)` but you are given the rewrite rule, you are only passing `/register/(.*)` so it doesn't match the rule.

Comment: drew is correct, where is the 2nd parameter you are trying to rewrite with?
Also you can make it optional by doing something like:
RewriteRule ^/register/(.*)[/(.*)]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rules to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/settings\.php$ settings.php?session=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^register/([^/]*)/(.*) register/$2?session=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

And remember RewriteRule start matching after first slash `/`.